# Networking Problems - Server controls client

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, unityscript, multiplayer

I'm trying to develop an online game where people can just hang out and chat, but for some reason the client's cube doesn't show up on the server's game and vice versa, but the server controls the client and the server. Here is the code for both files:

**Networking Script:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class NetworkManager : MonoBehaviour
{

string registeredGameName = "Hangout Zone";
bool isRefreshing = false;
float refreshRequestLength = 3.0f;
HostData[] hostData;

private void StartServer()
{
    Network.InitializeServer(16, 25002, false);
    MasterServer.RegisterHost(registeredGameName, "Hangout Zone", "The place to chill with friends.");
}

void OnServerInitialized()
{
    Debug.Log("Server has been initialized.");
}

void OnPlayerDisconnected(NetworkPlayer player)
{
    Debug.Log("Player disconnected.");
    Network.RemoveRPCs(player);
    Network.DestroyPlayerObjects(player);
}

void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    if (Network.isServer)
    {
        Network.Disconnect(200);
        MasterServer.UnregisterHost();
    }

    if (Network.isClient)
    {
        Network.Disconnect(200);
    }
}

void OnMasterServerEvent(MasterServerEvent masterServerEvent)
{
    if (masterServerEvent == MasterServerEvent.RegistrationSucceeded)
    {
        Debug.Log("Registration Successful.");
    }
}

public IEnumerator RefreshHostList()
{
    Debug.Log("Refreshing...");
    MasterServer.RequestHostList(registeredGameName);
    float timeStarted = Time.time;
    float timeEnd = Time.time + refreshRequestLength;

    while (Time.time < timeEnd)
    {
        hostData = MasterServer.PollHostList();
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

    if (hostData == null || hostData.Length == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("No active servers have been found.");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(hostData.Length + " have been found.");
    }

}

private void SpawnPlayer()
{
    Debug.Log("Spawning player...");
    Network.Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Block"), new Vector3(0f, 2.5f, 0f), Quaternion.identity, 0);
}



public void OnGUI()
{

    if (Network.isServer)
    {
        GUILayout.Label("Running as a server.");
    }
    else if (Network.isClient)
    {
        GUILayout.Label("Running as a client.");
    }

    if (Network.isClient)
    {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(25f, 25f, 150f, 30f), "Spawn"))
        {
            SpawnPlayer();
        }
    }
    if (Network.isClient || Network.isServer)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(25f, 25f, 150f, 30f), "Start New Server"))
    {
        StartServer();
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(25f, 65f, 150f, 30f), "Refresh Server List"))
    {
        StartCoroutine("RefreshHostList");
    }
    if (hostData != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < hostData.Length; i++)
        {
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2, 65f + (30f * i), 300f, 30f), hostData[i].gameName))
            {
                Network.Connect(hostData[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Control Script:** (This is JavaScript)

```
#pragma strict

function Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        transform.position.z += 0.03;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        transform.position.z -= 0.03;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        transform.position.x -= 0.03;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        transform.position.x += 0.03;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the player prefab added to the NetworkManager?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a `OnPlayerConnect` or something like that?
I only see `SpawnPlayer()`, and can't see it getting called from anywhere except the button.

Anyway, you are spawning a object with a local control. This means if the second player actually DID spawn more cubes, you would control all of them from all machines.
The control script needs to only respond if if sees that the local player is the owner of the object (since i suspect you have the script attached to all blocks spawned).

I think unity has this in the `NetworkView.isMine` property of the networkview. Add something like this to your controller script:

```
function Update () {
if (!networkView.isMine) { return; }
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
{
    transform.position.z += 0.03;
}
```

Comment: I added the OnPlayerConnect but still nothing's happening

Comment: I think there's something wrong with Network.Instantiate because whenever the player spawns it gives me an error for that but I have no idea how to fix it. I'll paste the exact error below.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with Network.Instantiate because whenever the player spawns it gives me an error for that but I have no idea how to fix it. I'll paste the exact error below.

Comment: Ok the error's gone now but it still is having issues

Comment: You have attached a `NetworkView` to the gameobject your instanciating?

Comment: You should add `if (!networkView.isMine) { return; }` to your controller script

Comment: Yup there's a network view in it. I tried the extra code you pasted but it just gives me an error.

Comment: You'll have to syntax check it yourself, if it's in java. I updated to the correct unity syntax..

Comment: I got the network view code to work and stop giving errors, but the exact same problem is still occurring.

Comment: If you have the prefab in the editor, remove it from the scene, and add a button for creating the serverside box as well trough script so that Network.Instanciate triggers. Other than that, its hard to help without seeing the code. Try randomizing the position you instanciate to. Might be easier if you see how many blocks are there (since now they spawn exactly over each other)

Comment: There's definitely something wrong with network.instantiate, I just did exactly what you said and on joining the server the block didn't spawn. I'll check the unity docs and make sure I haven't missed something out in the instantiate.

Comment: NullReferenceException
UnityEngine.Network.Instantiate (UnityEngine.Object prefab, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Int32 group) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/Networking.gen.cs:629)
NetworkManager.SpawnPlayer () (at Assets/NetworkManager.cs:83)
NetworkManager.OnServerInitialized () (at Assets/NetworkManager.cs:24)
UnityEngine.Network:InitializeServer(Int32, Int32, Boolean)
NetworkManager:StartServer() (at Assets/NetworkManager.cs:13)
NetworkManager:OnGUI() (at Assets/NetworkManager.cs:107)

Comment: Seems like you are trying to instantiate something that cannot be found. Are you sure `Resources.Load("Prefabs/Block")` is a valid location on both machines?